# Flink KeyedProcessFunction Ordering

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm new to Flink and trying to understand how Flink orders calls to `processElement()` in its `KeyedProcessFunction` abstraction under parallelism. Consider this example of producing a stream of partial sums:

```
package sample

import org.apache.flink.api.common.state.{ValueState, ValueStateDescriptor}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment, createTypeInformation}
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector

object Playground {
  case class Record(groupId: String, score: Int) {}

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // 1. Create the environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment()
    env.setParallelism(10)

    // 2. Source
    val record1 = Record("groupX", 1)
    val record2 = Record("groupX", 2)
    val record3 = Record("groupX", 3)
    val records: DataStream[Record] = env.fromElements(record1, record2, record3, record1, record2, record3)

    // 3. Application Logic
    val partialSums: DataStream[Int] = records
      .keyBy(record => record.groupId)
      .process(new KeyedProcessFunction[String, Record, Int] {
        // Store partial sum of score for Records seen
        lazy val partialSum: ValueState[Int] = getRuntimeContext.getState(
          new ValueStateDescriptor[Int]("partialSum", classOf[Int]))

        // Ingest new record
        override
        def processElement(value: Record,
                           ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[String, Record, Int]#Context,
                           out: Collector[Int]): Unit =
        {
          val currentSum: Int = partialSum.value()
          partialSum.update(currentSum + value.score)
          out.collect(partialSum.value())
        }
      })

    // 4. Sink
    partialSums.print()

    // 5. Build JobGraph and execute
    env.execute("sample-job")
  }
}
```

I would expect the output of this to be the stream: `1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12`. And indeed it is, here.

Is it safe to assume this will always be the case, particularly when reading from sources with large parallelism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the ordering is guaranteed *within each key*. Since there is only one key, you will always get `1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 12`.

When you are reading from a source with parallelism greater than one, then the various source instances will race against each other. When the streams from two or more sources are joined (e.g., via keyBy, union, rebalance, etc.), then the result is non-deterministic (but the events from each of the sources will keep their relative ordering).

For example, if you have

```
stream X: 1, 2, 3, 4
stream Y: a, b, c, d
```

and then bring those two streams together, you might get

`1, 2, 3, 4, a, b, c, d`, or `a, b, 1, 2, 3, c, 4, d`, etc.

Comment: Thanks David! As a follow-up, if I know that all data from "groupX" is inserted by a producer in-order in exactly one shard of an AWS Kinesis stream / Kafka topic (e.g., using a partition key), and knowing that the Flink connectors pull from shards sequentially, then I can be guaranteed data for groupX will travel through my Flink dataflow-DAG in-order? It seems that in this regime all data from groupX comes from one subtask and goes to one subtask, so ordering is preserved.

Comment: @synchronice you will need to ensure that your Flink application has the same parallelism as the kafka topic has partitions, and that there is no rebalance in between. to be honest I would not overly rely on this, also considering that most kafka producers don't necessarily always write messages in order.